# Dynamic list of checkboxes

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a list of AccessPrivileges and I would need to create a form with a dynamic list of checkboxes, however I cannot find a solution inside the documentation.

Assuming you have the following

```
class AccessPrivilege(dataType:String, description:String)

object AccessPrivilege {

 val privileges:Seq[AccessPrivilege] = ....

}
```

I would need to generate a binding so that , in my form I can:

- Have a checkbox whose label is the description
- Being able to retrieve the list of selected checkboxes as a List of String and not as a List of boolean.

I can't find among the form helpers what I need, because the checked returns a boolean, while I need to "collect" the selected checkboxes...